# Easiest way to calculate this indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

What's the easiest way to calculate the following indefinite integral:

$$ \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{2\sin(x)+3}} \mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: Notice that the numerator is (up to a constant factor) the derivative of the radicand.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I phrased that same thought in a rather different way in my posted answer.  But I wonder if it's reasonable to expect a lay reader to understand technical terms like "up to".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx=2\sqrt{f(x)}+C$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this interesting approach, I will accept your answer in next 5 minutes.

Comment: I think you're missing an integral sign there.

Comment: Of course, hehe. Thanks, @DavidZhang

Answer (score 3):

set $u=2\sin(x)+3$. then $du=2\cos(x)dx$.
So it is 
$$
\int \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First, make the substitution $u = 2\sin(x) + 3$.  Then, $du = 2\cos(x) \,dx$.  Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{2\sin(x) + 3}}dx &= \int \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}\\
&= \sqrt{u} + C\\
&= \ldots
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sin x+3}}\Big( \cos x \, dx \Big)
$$

If you don't know what that is hinting at, then that is what you need to learn about integration by substitution.